# How to get back to the app after registering with facebook account?

Tags: ios

I am trying to build an app that requires facebook authentication like registering users through their facebook account. Problem is after user logs into facebook am not able to get back into my app

Comment: Did you see the documentations properly, they have written everything there.. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the Info section or info.plist of the project, there is a tab of URL types. In URL Types section you have to enter your facebook id that you got by creating facebook developer's account with 'fb' in prefix. Also identifier needs to be entered so that the OS knows which app to get back again